# pdflatex problem with seminar in texlive-2021

Tags: pdflatex, tex-live

I recently encountered problem with seminar class.
I am using app-text/texlive-2021 on Gentoo Linux.

Simple test case:

```
\documentclass{seminar}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
pet@pvn ~/Documents/work $ pdflatex pokus.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021 Gentoo Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pokus.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/seminar/seminar.cls
Document Class: seminar 2014/01/17, 1.61
Documentclass: `seminar' v1.61 <2014/01/17> (tvz,hv)
```

...

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/seminar/sem-page.sty))
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \the \before@document \begingroup \UseOneTimeHook {beg...
l.3 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me with texlive 2021. Can you show your complete .log file?

Comment: Well, it is too long to paste it to comment and I do not see the possibility to a attach file to this forum.

Comment: You could use something like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SzRbWRxN

Comment: You're documentclass is not up-to-date, the current version from texlive2021 is 1.63a

Comment: Thank you. That means that the problem is somewhere in the texlive package in my distribution. I will check this.

Comment: Can you try to update the class with `tlmgr update seminar` or `tlmgr update --all` to get all packages updated?

Comment: Yes, I installed texlive manually from https://www.tug.org/texlive/ to bypass my distribution packages and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using ? This fails for me too with TeX Live 2021 on Gentoo.

Comment: Looking at the above referenced log in pastebin, you are using Gentoo with TeX Live 2021 as well.

Comment: filed https://bugs.gentoo.org/816816 to track this in Gentoo Linux.

Comment: the problem seems to be present on Arch Linux as well.